# What should be the datasource configuration for cosmosdb in springboot project to use JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, azure-cosmosdb

I have provided the `azure.cosmosdb.uri`, `azure.cosmosdb.key` and `azure.cosmosdb.database` definition in my `application.properties` file.

When I am using `DocumentDbRepository`, I am able to perform CRUD operations to my cosmos db.

I want to use JDBC template for my project to write customize queries using `JDBCTemplate.queryForString()` methods. I autowired the `JDBCTemplate` class in my DAO class:

But still I am getting the below error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

**Description**:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

**Action**:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

**DAO class code**-

```
package com.walmart.Ods;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TechDAO{

   public void select(String id)
   {
       String queryString = "SELECT * FROM [DATABASE_NAME] g WHERE g.id = ? ";

       @Autowired
       private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        List<Map<String, Object>> result = 
   getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(queryString, new Object[]{id});

  }

}
```

application.properties file -

```
azure.cosmosdb.uri=***

azure.cosmosdb.key=***

azure.cosmosdb.database=***
```

pom.xml file -

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.1.8.RELEASE
         
    
    com.walmart
    Ods
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    Ods
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <azure.version>2.1.7</azure.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: did you add appropriate dependency in your pom.xml ?

Comment: Hello Sakshi , Is JDBC support available for CosmosDB. You are much better off using spring starter for CosmosDB (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-cosmos-db?view=azure-java-stable) and then use API's in repository

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G The project from this link I am able to use and run properly but I wanted to write my customize SQL queries (Use Joins, SQL operators and complex queries).
When I use DocumentDbRepository, I can use only the predefined CRUD operations available in this repository but I want to write complex queries.

I am not sure whether JDBC support is available for CosmosDB or not.

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Comment: @ShameeraAnuranga I have added my pom file in the question now, kindly check.

Comment: What Ramachandran said is correct. The "Query" annotation is not supported yet for  "azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter"   [link](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/issues/385)

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G
Is there any way I can write customize queries for cosmos db?
If you can share any link also it will work.

Comment: As i understand , you cannot issue plain SQL commands on CosmosDB. There is support for a similar operations that you would do on a database. What is your requirement ?

Comment: My requirement to to create backend APIs for my project where the non custom methods won’t suffice.... I want to fetch data using like, And, Or operators so I need to write my custom queries as the methods offered by DocumentDbRepository have only simple find, save options.

Comment: Sakshi , you will not be able to use SQL like commands for join on CosmosDB.  You may be able to add predicates like AND , OR. Joins , aggregations etc are rather difficult with direct starter API!

Comment: Please see the Azure Cosmos DB query sandbox where there is a JOIN example: https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo